# How to get Map key?

Tags: groovy

I have key-value pair as UUID's and trying to get key for process but it is returning value in the loop. Please help how to get key map ?

Input Value :

```
mapValues = [88891108-2dfd-41a1-9a92-f2200acc561c:12fd254d-98d0-4c0e-9ac9-9ccd5494075a]
```

code:

```
for(mapKey in sourceCodeMap.keySet())
{
println(sourceCodeMap[mapKey])
}
```

output:

```
12fd254d-98d0-4c0e-9ac9-9ccd5494075a
```

But iam expecting 88891108-2dfd-41a1-9a92-f2200acc561c as key. How to get left most value as key from map ?

Comment: Then change line to this: println mapKey

Comment: You are iterating all **keys** of that map and then load the **value** for that key and print it in your code. As stated, the solution is to _not_ fetch the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Groovy idiom is to use `.each()` to iterate the map:

```
def mapValues = ['88891108-2dfd-41a1-9a92-f2200acc561c':'12fd254d-98d0-4c0e-9ac9-9ccd5494075a']

mapValues.each { key, value ->
    println key
}
```